# Story ID - early humans with telepathic ability wiped out by predatory cats

Tags: story-identification

I got such a quick and accurate answer to my first question that I'm going to try another one.  I'm trying to remember the name and details of a story I read a while back.  It's set in prehistoric times.  There are two rival groups of humans, one of which are more or less plain old early human, and the other of which are the same except they have some sort of organ or gland or something that allows them to communicate telepathically.  Both groups are menaced by big predatory cats, saber-tooth tigers or something of that nature.  By the end of the story, the telepathic group has been wiped out, for some reason that isn't strictly their fault.  That's all the details I remember.  Can anyone place this?

Comment: Can you estimate a publication date? Remember any specific characters/scenes, Cover details etc.

Comment: It wasn't recent.  70s, 80's?  I don't remember any details, but the general idea was that it explained why the telepathy capability, which seems like it should confer an evolutionary advantage, didn't survive natural selection.

Comment: Were other protohuman subtypes described?